# surjectivity of an operator which is defined on some set of analytic functions

Tags: complex-analysis, banach-spaces

For a fixed function $h\in H(\mathbb{D})$ and a fixed complex number $λ$ let $f$ (It is analytic) be a solution of
$$(λI − C)f = h.$$
Using Taylor expansions, it is easy to see that the operator $(λI − C)$ is bijective unless $1/λ$ is a positive integer and that the range of the operator $((1/n)I − C), n ∈ Z^{+}$, does not contain the function $z→z^n−1$. My question how do you conclude the fact using Taylor expansion???
Sorry $C$ is the Cesaro operator                                                                                     $$Cf (z) = \frac{1}{z}\int_{0}^z\frac{f (ζ)}{1−ζ}dζ.$$

Comment: What is $C$?  Can you give a definition?  Cheers!

Comment: Sorry $C$ is the Cesaro operator

Comment: And $\vert z \vert < 1$, right?

Comment: yes |z|<1. Also $C$ has another formula

Comment: You mean the Cesaro mean of a series?

Comment: Yes exactly....

Comment: Is $\Bbb D \subset \Bbb C$ the (open) unit disk?  That is, does $\Bbb D = \{z \in \Bbb C \mid \vert z \vert < 1\}$?

Comment: Oops!  Looks like I already asked that last one!  Never mind . . .